# String substitution within ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string

I have the following code, within which I want to change certain values to csv friendly, e.g., 'nil' to ''. I need to know how to make these changes. Thank you.

```
  def daily_door_schedule
    @tickets = Ticket.where(active: true).
      pluck(
        :door_manufacturer,
        :job_number, 
        :door_style, 
        :door_allocation_date,
        :date_doors_received_in_aub, 
        :door_delivery_due_date,
        :notes
      )

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { render text: @tickets.to_csv }
    end
  end
```

Comment: `to_csv` can handle `nil` values, it results in an empty field

Comment: What is the specific problem? The CSV class doesn't create strings containing the word 'nil'.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have methods `where` or `pluck`. If they're not defined in `Ticket`, you need at least one more tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@tickets = Ticket.where(active: true).
  pluck(
    :door_manufacturer,
    :job_number, 
    :door_style, 
    :door_allocation_date,
    :date_doors_received_in_aub, 
    :door_delivery_due_date,
    :notes
  ).map { |ticket| ticket.map(&:to_s) }
```

Comment: Anthony, this is what happens when you don't use your reading glasses.I think you want `el ||= ''`. If `el` is a string or `nil`, you could also write `ticket.map(&:to_s)`, but I guess you want strings anyway. (I say this without knowing what `pluck` does.)

Comment: I just went to the optometrist for the first time in my life 2 weeks ago... your comment couldn't be more appropriate.  As always, thank you for the suggestion - it's perfect.